# Making android app run on proxy authorized internet

Tags: android, android-volley, firewall, proxy-server

I have created an app with following internet related permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

My app makes calls to nodejs server through volley. When I run my app on my home wifi, it works fluently and all network behavior are as expected. But when I run it on college wifi, which is authorized by a proxy server, the app does not work at all. Probably the wifi does not allow the app to access internet.

Note: I have provided my proxy authorization credentials on my phone and all other apps run perfectly on the college wifi.

Kindly suggest me on how to overcome this.